R package "keras3" error: OP_REQUIRES failed at reshape_op.h:65 : INVALID_ARGUMENT: Only one input size may be -1, not both 0 and 1
I am following the example in Chapter 10 of the book "Deep Learning with R, 2nd Edition", using the R package keras3. An error occurs:

W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1841] OP_REQUIRES failed at
reshape_op.h:65 : INVALID_ARGUMENT: Only one input size may be -1, not
both 0 and 1.

I am new to the deep learning framework in R, and I wonder how to fix this error?
The book has provided the dataset in this link.
library(keras3)
library(dplyr)

# Preparing the Data 
full_df <- readr::read_csv("jena_climate_2009_2016.csv")

full_df$`Date Time` %<>%                     
  as.POSIXct(tz = "Etc/GMT+1", format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")

num_train_samples <- round(nrow(full_df) * 0.5)
num_val_samples <- round(nrow(full_df) * 0.25)
num_test_samples <- nrow(full_df) - num_train_samples - num_val_samples

train_df <- full_df[seq(num_train_samples), ]
val_df <- full_df[seq(from = nrow(train_df) + 1,
                  length.out = num_val_samples), ]
test_df <- full_df[seq(to = nrow(full_df),
                   length.out = num_test_samples), ]

## Normalize the data
input_data_colnames <- names(full_df) %>%
  setdiff(c("Date Time"))                                  

normalization_values <-
  zip_lists(mean = lapply(train_df[input_data_colnames], mean),
            sd = lapply(train_df[input_data_colnames], sd))
str(normalization_values)

normalize_input_data <- function(df) {
  normalize <- function(x, center, scale)
    (x - center) / scale

  for(col_nm in input_data_colnames) {
    col_nv <- normalization_values[[col_nm]]
    df[[col_nm]] %<>% normalize(., col_nv$mean, col_nv$sd)
  }
  df
}

## Instantiating datasets for training, validation, and testing
sampling_rate <- 6
sequence_length <- 120
delay <- sampling_rate * (sequence_length + 24 - 1)
batch_size <- 256

df_to_inputs_and_targets <- function(df) {
  inputs <- df[input_data_colnames] %>%
    normalize_input_data() %>%
    as.matrix()

  targets <- as.array(df$`T (degC)`)

  list(head(inputs, -delay), tail(targets, -delay))           
}

make_dataset <- function(df) {
  c(inputs, targets) %<-% df_to_inputs_and_targets(df)       

  timeseries_dataset_from_array(                                              
    inputs, targets,
    sampling_rate = sampling_rate,
    sequence_length = sequence_length,
    shuffle = TRUE,
    batch_size = batch_size
  )
}

train_dataset <- make_dataset(train_df)
val_dataset <- make_dataset(val_df)
test_dataset <- make_dataset(test_df)


## A densely connected model
ncol_input_data <- length(input_data_colnames)

inputs <- layer_input(shape = c(sequence_length, ncol_input_data))

outputs <- inputs %>%
  layer_flatten() %>%
  layer_dense(16, activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dense(1)

model <- keras_model(inputs, outputs)

callbacks = list(
  callback_model_checkpoint("jena_dense.keras",
                            save_best_only = TRUE)
)

model %>%
  compile(optimizer = "rmsprop",
          loss = "mse",
          metrics = "mae")

history <- model %>%
  fit(train_dataset,
      epochs = 10,
      validation_data = val_dataset,
      callbacks = callbacks)

model <- load_model_tf("jena_dense.keras")
sprintf("Test MAE: %.2f", evaluate(model, test_dataset)["mae"])



Just a heads up. I had issues with the keras package that was version dependent. Took me waaaay too long to figure out. My recurrent neural net would run fine on one version but not at all on another. Same code ran fine with R version 4.3.1 but I couldn't get it to run on 4.3.0. I was trying to move to 4.3.0 because different library I was using for an unrelated part of the project had a memory leak with 4.3.1.

@noNameTed Would you please check my question? Thanks.

This seems to be a known issue that happens when running keras3 with code for keras2. The simple fix for this would be that you should use keras instead of keras3 library like in the book original code
library(keras)


Is it possible to fix or revise the code to make it work under keras3? Thanks.
